# Angular Resource object not persisting outside of Service scope in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my Ionic application, using ngResource, I have my factory defined in a js/services.js file as such:

```
angular.module('story.services', ['ngResource'])

.factory('StatsService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/v1/total_view_count', {}, {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}});

});
```

...the in my controllers.js I have the following call:

```
      var testCallback; 

      var request= StatsService.query(function(response) {
            console.log("RESPONSE: " + response.total_views );
            testCallback = response.total_views; //just testing if this works too. it doesn't.
        });

        console.log("RESULTS: " + request.total_views );
        console.log("RESULTS: " + testCallback );
```

Now the RESPONSE in the in the fuction(response) callback is showing the correct output for response.total_views...however, outside of that where I'm outputting "RESULTS" it is not. 'request.total_views" and testCallback both just display "undefined".

I'm new to Ionic and Angular so any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's async, you cannot do anything with the data outside the context of the callback because the data doesn't exist yet. It's an async problem unrelated to ionic or angular.

Comment: That makes sense. Though typically in angular an $http call would follow by a `.then()` since there is a promise to save and return the data. I assumed ngResource would work by giving a promise... but does it not?

Comment: @askilondz objects returned by `$resource` have a property attached  named `$promise` that has a `$q` promise suitable for chaining with its `.then` method. Otherwise data properties are added to the resource object by the `$resource` service asynchronously as the XHR resolves. This works for clients like `ng-repeat` which `$watch` the object but it doesn't work for `console.log`. For more information see the [AngularJS $resource API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite often, you dont need to use callbacks for $resource. In controller:

```
  $scope.result= StatsService.query();
```

In html:

```
<div ng-if="result.$resolved">
{{result.total_views}}
</div>
```

If you want to perform some javascript, then use callback:

```
  var result1= StatsService.query(function() {
       // result1 already resolved here
    });
```

Also notice that you query method is same as default $resource.get, so you can just remove it and use get() instead.

Comment: Thanks. My problem really was trying to output the results with javascript but like you said that should just be in callback which is why that part was what was working for me.  Using the `.$resolved` in the `ng-if` helped as well. Thanks again.